# populating fields in PHP with MySQLi Array

Tags: php

Can I get a quick reality check?

The idea that I'm working on is that I have text in a HTML template that looks like `{Field1}` and I want to populate the values for that field from a MySQLi connection where the database field is `Field1`.

So in theory I should get the data in an array, then cycle through that array, (adding `{}` and) replacing the text in the HTML with the required values.

Is there a more elegant solution to my task here or is what I'm planning pretty much it?

Does anyone have any advice or tutorials on handling the associated array returned by MySQLi? Much appreciated. I'm still learning and I'm just banging my head on this problem for a bit too long.

Comment: Can you post an example ?

Comment: do you mean something like [Mustache](http://mustache.github.io/) is already doing ? (its open source)

Comment: Thanks guys, but Sanuel Jackson told me of the array_map() function which does what I'm looking for. I'll look into mustache though because it looks quite interesting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without seeing your source for PHP, it is VERY difficult to answer this question,

I believe what you want to do can be achieved using *array_map*

Following would add the braces as you wish around each element in the array

```
// $row = .... your getter from mysqli connection

$row = array_map("apply_braces", $row);



// end of loops and stuff -- begin functions below
function apply_braces($field) {
    return '{' . $field . '}';
}
```

The above will set all values in $row, to "{" . $somevalue . "}",  so whatever the value of the item in the array is, it will add the braces around it using the custom function.

Comment: This is the answer I'm looking for. The array returned from the mysqli connection can't be parsed easily (at my skill level anyway) and this array_map function looks like exactly what I should be using. I'll try it out later today.

Answer (score 0):

Sure.

Check failed.

### Do not re-invent the wheel.

Your idea on templates is wrong. Please learn how to use already existing templating systems before trying to create your own.

> Does anyone have any advice or tutorials on handling the associated array returned by MySQLi?

### Definitely NO.

Simply because there is absolutely nothing special in the associative arrays returned from mysql. They are exactly the same as any other associative array in PHP, no difference.